# What is time complexity involved for finding an element in Various STLs

Tags: list, dictionary, vector, queue, deque

Can anyone help me with the time complexity involved in finding a value in various STL Containers

1. Vectors
2. deque
3. list
4. string
5. set
6. multiset
7. map
8. multimap
9. stack
10. queue
11. priority queue.

I think, the search/find time should be based on how these STL containers are implemented internally. So it would help if information about same can be provided as well. It might vary from implementation to implementation, so answers based on commonly used data structures behind these STL containers would also help.

Thanks in advance..